# Entity Framework Migration cant find connection string in App.config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a second project in my solution called DataAccess (.NET Framework Class Library) for models. I set my main asp .net mvc project as start up and from package manager console I set DataAccess as default. I already have an existing database. So I installed Entity Framework in DataAccess layer using `package-install` command to get the latest. Then I added an Entity Data Model. But whenever I try to run `enable-migrations` from PM it shows that `No connection string named 'MAHMHEntities' could be found in the application config file.` Although there is a connectionString in App.config called `MAHMHEntities`. In my MAHMHEntities.cs class I have declared the connection string:

```
namespace DataAccess.Entities
{
  using System.Data.Entity;

  public partial class MAHMHEntities : DbContext
  {
    public MAHMHEntities()
        : base("name=MAHMHEntities")
    {
    }  
    //other dbset classes
  }  
}
```

In DataAccess layer I have App.config file that has two connectionString, I added the `DefaultConnection` myself :

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQL2014;Initial Catalog=MAHMH;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="MAHMHEntities" connectionString="data source=.\SQL2014;initial catalog=MAHMH;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  
</connectionStrings>
```

Whichever connection I use I always get the same error when I try to enable migration. Entity Framework version is 6.2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set Data access project as start up project. Or you can add your connection string to web application's(Which is currently start up project) web.config

Comment: but my start up project is the main asp.net mvc app. i just want to move all the models to another layer. is that possible?

Comment: just for migration set start up project as dal

Comment: i did and it worked. then i made my main project as startup again. then i tried to add a migration and the error shows again.

Comment: have you add conneciton string to web.config? (Which is main project)